# Integrating Disqus comment in Android App

Tags: android, disqus

I had made an application with the help of following links, But When I login to Disqus for entering comment, I need to refresh the page, only then it shows I am logged in and then I can enter the comment. I am using the HTML snippet rather than php one.
The links I am referring are:-

http://globeotter.com/blog/disqus-android-code/

http://globeotter.com/blog/disqus-login-and-logout/

My code is below:-

```
    Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webDisqus;
    String sMyurl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        String htmlComments = getHtmlComment("<MyWEBSITE_Disqus_ID>", "<MYWEBSITE_SHORTNAME>");
         sMyurl="MYWEBSITES_URL";
        webDisqus = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.disqus);
        // set up disqus
        WebSettings webSettings2 = webDisqus.getSettings();
        webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings2.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webDisqus.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webDisqus.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(htmlComments, "text/html", null, sMyurl));
        webDisqus.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webDisqus.loadData(htmlComments, "text/html", null);
    }

        public String getHtmlComment(String idPost, String shortName) {
     return "<div id='disqus_thread'></div>"
+ "<script type='text/javascript'>"
+ "var disqus_identifier = '"
+ idPost
+ "';"
+ "var disqus_shortname = '"
+ shortName
+ "';"
+ " (function() { var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;"
+ "dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';"
+ "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();"
+ "</script>";
}
}
```

And MyWebView class is as follows:-

`

```
 public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {`

    private String html_comments, sType, obj, sMyURL;


     public MyWebViewClient(String htmlComments, String string, String object, String URL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         html_comments=htmlComments;
         sType=string;
         obj=object;
         sMyURL=URL;
    }
    @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
     Log.i("page started", url);
     }

    @Override
     public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Log.i("disqus error", "failed: " + failingUrl + ", error code: " + errorCode + " [" + description + "]");
     }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     if(url.indexOf("logout")>-1 || url.indexOf("disqus.com/next/login-success")>-1 ){
     view.loadData(html_comments, sType, obj);

     }
     if(url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/twitter/complete")>-1||url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/facebook/complete")>-1||url.indexOf("disqus.com/_ax/google/complete")>-1){
     view.loadData(html_comments, sType, obj);

     }
     if(url.indexOf(sMyURL+"/login.php")>-1){
     view.loadData(html_comments,sType, obj);
    }
    }
    }`
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do to not refresh the page whenever I login and logout from Disqus through the WebView of my Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the above code runs well on Android Devices. Only the problem occurs if we run it on Emulator, as Emulator are slow as compared to Devices...